# insert in database mysql not work correctly

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem that i will insert in database mysql from android 
this information student id - section id -current date -Status 
each time that user click the buttons it will insert this information in database
also i check if the record is duplicate if it is i will told the user you already insert
but if not it will insert correctly
i try to insert and by change every time the date 
but it said you already insert 
how can i solve this problem so i can insert every time a change the date in my database

Comment: a) You're taking user input and using it directly in a query without any escaping or validation.  This leaves your database wide open to SQL injection attacks. b) The mysql_* family of functions is deprecated in all but name, and should be avoided.  Please look into using mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: why i can not insert more the one time even when i change the date  it is not insert only one times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only checking, if the user has given input for the fields or not.
And before inserting the record, you are not checking if such record already exists in database or not.
And may be because of unique constraint if any defined, next inserts are rejected with an exception due to data duplication in fresh input from the user.

Check if any constraints are defined for data uniqueness.
Based on them handle exceptions and inform user accordingly.

Comment: Check if any constraints are defined for data uniqueness how can i do it can you help me ?

Comment: execute `show create table attends;` and see what it displays. And show us the same.

Comment: i edit some change in my answer look at it if there is other way u can show you creation told me

Comment: if you have access to mysql console execute `show create table attends;` and update your posting with that output. I think `phpMyAdmin` too supports this execution.

Comment: i try to find it but i do know how i do i print screen that may help you to find the option http://im30.gulfup.com/SLQn1.png

Comment: @sara, Structure of the table given does not help. On phpadmin page, click on `SQL` tab and type `show create table attends` in the text area and submit it to see the results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18667/discussion-between-ravinder-and-sara)